# Can a Bash shell option be set for a single command?

Tags: command-line, bash

I like the way a variable can be set for a single command, such as:

```
LANG=fr_FR.utf8 df -h
```

Is it possible to use the `shopt -s` command, or some other method, to set a shell option, such as nullglob or extglob, for a single command in the same manner?

Comment: Ah I see, use `shopt -s` at the start and `-u` at the end? I suppose the command itself would be an argument too, along with its own arguments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on your use case, use a subshell:

```
(shopt -s nullglob; foo)
```

Comment: I thought that was one possibility. If I needed to pass variables to the subshell, do I just export them beforehand?

Comment: @Arronical pass to commands? Then yes.

Comment: That's just what I needed! I was looking echo a single command, and this works perfectly with `(set -x; foo)`.